# Python task. Converting for to while

Tags: python

I just began programming and one of the tasks i got was making code that gives out prizes depending on the laps done. I began completing the exercise without realizing that i should be using a while loop in it, so here it is and i don't know how to make it work with a while loop.

```
to = int(input("Laps: "))

start = 1

prize = 0
for i in range(start, to+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        prize = prize + i
        
print("Prize: " + str(prize))
```

Comment: So you expect to just get the solution from someone else? It would be much more productive to you to actually try that and ask here about ***your*** code using a `while` loop

Comment: I tried to make it work with the while loop, but it just did not work. So i posted the code that actually worked, but not the correct way.

Comment: It would be better to post your actually failed attempt with the `while`. This way we can help stir you in the right direction. Right now we don't know what you're doing wrong and how to help you...

Comment: There is always room for improvement, understood.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
to = int(input("Laps: "))

i = 1
prize = 0

while i < (to+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        prize = prize + i
    i = i + 1

print("Prize: " + str(prize))
```

It is essentially the same as your `for` loop. The main difference is that in a `while` loop you have to  update the progress of your loop yourself, which is what the statement `i = i + 1` is for.